Thumping in rear wheel when driving 80ks
Hello I have a Holden commodore an it makes a thumping noise on left rear side by the tyre can some one help me an tell wat it is please it only comes when u driving 80/100ks

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is your Commodore? How many miles (KMs) are on it? What is the thumping noise like (can you describe it better)?  When you say it happens at 80/100ks, do you mean no noise until 80ks, then goes away again over 100ks?
